# View (MKMapView) resizes when navigation bar gets hidden

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I've added a `MKMapView` as a subview to the `view` of a view controller (embedded in a navigation controller. Then I've used anchors to pin it to the sides of my view like so:

```
mapView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true
mapView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true
mapView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true 
mapView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
```

When I use `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` to hide my navigation bar, the `mapView` gets taller as if it was anchored not to the top of my `view`, but at the bottom of my navigation bar. How can I avoid this? I want the navigation bar to slide out of the screen leaving a fullscreen mapView with same position/height.

Thank you!

Comment: try this:
mapView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topLayoutGuide).active = true

Comment: "UIView does not have a member named topLayoutGuide" :(

Comment: mapView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true

Comment: It compiles but I achieve the same effect as before

Comment: Make sure **Extend Edges Under Top Bars** is selected for your `view` in the *Attributes Inspector*.

Comment: Thanks! I do not user storyboards but I've used         extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

Answer (score 0):

`extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` on the view controller does the work.

**Extended Edges Under Top Bars** in the Attributes Inspector if using storyboards.